Keeping ref list of html elements of long v-for list causes performance problem
Task
I have a long list of elements in a v-for list. I want to call .focus() on the next element when pressing "arrow-down".
What I tried
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const htmlElements = ref([])
const elements = Array.from({ length: 5_000 }, (_, i) => ({ text: 'Element'+ i }))
</script>

<template>
 <p v-for="el of elements" ref="htmlElements">{{ el.text }}</p>
</template>

Vue Playground
I have a long list of elements and I keep a list of the corresponding dom elements from the v-for loop to call focus on these elements (omitted for clarity).
Problem
ref="htmlElements" causes a massive performance problem. When accessing the dom elements of the list via the native childNodes property of the parent, I don't see a performance problem, but it does seem brittle (e.g., includes #text nodes I need to filter out).
Question
How can I get a performant and vue-compliant way to call focus on the child nodes?

Not sure but you could start by adding a key to the iteration. Then maybe try to have either the ref on each child or one level higher. Not sure which one is better but there is definitely the overhead of having something that tracks the reactivity on a big object. Maybe some kind of shallowRef for the templating might help. Otherwise you could also skip the whole rendering of each element by rendering only the ones visible in the viewport with the virtual scroll package for Vue. There are probably other way of solving this issue with regular JS + web perf approaches but those one are a good

Start overall. For the rest, I think they overall any kind of reactivity based framework might be struggling when it comes down to 5000 elements and DOM/virtual DOM management. So start by the biggest things that might impact the performance of it. Also maybe Vue can be skipped for that part altogether because might be overkill. Overall, more details about your project and what you're trying to accomplish might be welcome so that we understand that this is not a XY problem.

For this it might be easier to give each item an id that you can also set as the :key and then use vanilla js document.getElementById(id).focus()

@Thomas not really the way to go with Vue unfortunately.

@kissu I know, but if the only purpose is to set the focus it is an overkill to have a virtual DOM for the whole list and as refs to each node. I don't think there is a performant way with Vue in this scenario

@Thomas fair. Hence why I said that Vue might not be the best fit for that kind of job above. Vue Vapor might help a bit with this tho, but there is no ETA as of today, unfortunately.

shallowRef actually did the trick, thank you for your help. We will also look into overhauling the component in general, but it's nice to have this minimal and quick  solution for now.

OP achieved to have a good enough performance by using shallowRef, this is not the most optimal solution but good enough for a quick fix until a bigger revamp.
